# C# Save a copy of a text file after replacing values with .Replace

Tags: c#, asp.net, text-files

I have a method that i am using to replace values in a txt file.

```
  protected void SendFormData(NameValueCollection formData)
            {
                string fileName = Server.MapPath("/_TextTemplate/textTemplate.txt");
                string emailBody = File.ReadAllText(fileName);


                foreach (string val in formData.AllKeys)
                {
                    emailBody = emailBody.Replace("##"+ val +"##", formData[val]);

                }
    }
```

I plan on saving a copy of this text file after i have replaced the values. How can give this file a logical name and save a copy of it in my directory?

I did some googleing and `File.WriteAllLines` keeps popping up.

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"/_TextTemplate/" + formData[0] + ".txt", formData[0]);
```

But VS is complaining about that.

Comment: Look into the `StreamWriter` class.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx

Comment: Do you want File.WriteAllText? File.WriteAllLines is expecting an IEnumerable<string> and your example is only trying to write a string `formData[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File.WriteAllLines

Expects an `IEnumerable<string>` as an argument. You want

```
File.WriteAllText(@"/_TextTemplate/" + formData[0] + ".txt", formData[0])
```